# In laravel, session use memcached driver, Each request will be reset session expire stored in the memcached

Tags: php, laravel, session, memcached

in app\session.php ,lifetime is 1 minute.
when I logined,in memcached,session is this:

```
stats items
STAT items:7:number 1
STAT items:7:age 29
STAT items:7:evicted 0
STAT items:7:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:7:evicted_time 0
STAT items:7:outofmemory 0
STAT items:7:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:7:reclaimed 0
STAT items:7:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:7:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:7:crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT items:7:crawler_items_checked 0
STAT items:7:lrutail_reflocked 0
END
```

but when I visit url '/home' or '/',any url,this session's age in memcached will be reset.but when i do not visit any url, this session will be expired after one minute. this is a feature or a bug in laravel?

Comment: Memcache manages expiration on it's own. For the expiration to be updated on a request, it would mean Laravel is calling `put()` on it again on each request. Something like: `Cache::store('memcached')->put('bar', 'baz', 1);`

Comment: I find that each request will be accompanied by a set-cookie reply, even if my request has a cookie, the set-cookie in response will reset max-age